# Are there EXPTIME-complete problems which are also in IP?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, interactive-proof-systems

I am wondering if there are known to be any EXPTIME-complete problems (or even just problems in EXPTIME) which are known to also be in IP, so a prover can convince a verifier that an answer to an EXPTIME problem is say "yes" in polynomial time?  Although this seems like a natural question that maybe is solved, if the answer is yes, there are EXPTIME-complete problems in IP, would this not prove that $PSPACE=EXPTIME$ because $IP=PSPACE$?